# UITableView "Content" field not appearing in XIB file (Xcode 5 & 6)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I'm having a weird issue that I'm really not sure what to do about. The problem is simple: In one Xcode project (both in Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 Beta 4), I see "Content" and "Prototype Cells" when I click on a `UITableView` in a ***storyboard*** file:

[image: Expected result]

However, in another project, these are simply not appearing in an ***XIB*** file:

[image: Actual result]

Does anyone have any idea how to get "Content" and "Prototype Cells" to consistently appear in both `.storyboard` and `.xib` files? Thanks!

Comment: after about 6 years (!) this problem still exists. for others facing this problem: you can't use this attribute when using .xib file. check this if just need 1 cell in it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62369167/5853262

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope you are looking this UITableView in the Storyboard only.

When I was looking for your problem's solution I found the below observations :

1. When I Drag TableView over a View Controller / TableViewController to storyboard, 
   Then I found First screenshot in Attribute Inspector.

When I created a xib file by using File-> New-> File -> Objective C file and selected UitableViewController with interface builder.

Then I found Second screenshot in Attribute Inspector.

I hope this might help you.

Comment: Wow that's a really good observation. I didn't even realize that in one project I was using an XIB file and the other had a storyboard file (late night). Any idea how to get this to work in XIB files (I've edited my question)? Thanks so much!

Comment: @rebllo85: Thanks for that. Can you please select the above answer as correct one?

Comment: even though this didn't solve the problem, it pointed me in the right direction. Accepted, thanks.

Comment: Regarding your question, I guess no there isn't any settings available   by which we can get "Content" and "Prototype Cells" to consistently appear in both .storyboard and .xib files. Still, I will look look for more on this.

Comment: I currently understand that you can not use dynamic prototype table in .xib files, you can create it in the story board or you must do it by code.

Comment: That is actually very disappointing, storyboards grow like crazy, and this is the only way to insert custom cells in tableviews?

Answer (score 2):

Similar Issue Here - beginner here, so my wording may be incorrect (apologise in advance)

**Description**: When opening Main Storyboard and clicking on the TableView "*view controller*" icon I don't see "*Content Attribute*" within the "*Attribute Inspector*"

**Issue**: It looks like the actual table within the scene needs to be selected. When in Storyboard view and clicking on TableView view controller icon, this shows the attributes of the scene for TableView, which is not what you want, you want to select the actual table and not the entire TableView scene.

**Resolution**: I found two ways to select the actual table itself. 1.) with the TableView view controller selected, press the tab key(this cycles you though each object within a scene), until the  table is selected. (the table should appear highlighted)
2.) Above the project view, I have the navigation bar, where I see the hierarchical view of my entire project. Like the following: Main.storyboard --> TableView Scene --> TableView --> etc.
Under Tableview I clicked on "*Table View*" and this highlighted the Table.
For me, method 1 & 2 worked and now I'm able to see the content attribute "*Dynamic Prototypes*" under "*Table View*" of the "*Attributes Inspector*"