# Cannot add a PrototypeCell to UITableView inside xib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am new in IOS. I want to create a `UITableView` in a xib file instead of my `Main.storyboard`.
But the problem is when I drag a `UITableViewCell` in to `UITableView`, it does not work like in `Main.storyboard`.
My `Main.storyboard` now have many screen so it's very slow when load and also it's hard to find any screen. Therefore, I want to put put `UITableView` to xib file.

Do I miss something or I make something wrong?
Any help would be appreciated

Here is the describe image 
[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I'm sorry, but prototype cells are available only in storyboard-based projects. Hopefully you won't have gone too far down the xib approach and can try multiple storyboards instead. If you find them a bit overwhelming, it's OK; they get better – note that you don't have to have one storyboard for all your view controllers. You can have several, either linked in code or using storyboard references.

If you want to stick with xibs, another option is to use `registerNib` in code. So you design your prototype cells in xibs, then register them in code. Not quite as smooth, but it might suit your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your explain. I will try to create prototype cell in xibs

Comment: Wow, this used to work in Xib, IIRC. They removed this functionality just recently.

Comment: you did great r & d.

Answer (score 21):

Please check out this process.Follow this and you will get a custom cell to table

[image: Create Table]

[image: Create New Class for Cell]

[image: Make this class subclass of UITableViewCell]

[image]

[image: Use this code to create custom cell to show in table]

[image: do not forget to import custom cell]

Comment: Question about last image: Is there a reason we still have to dequeue the last cell, if it's always going to be nil anyway?
Because the line after that simply does a nil check, and then initializes the nib cell

Comment: Instead of a series of screenshot (of your whole screen no less) please provide an explanation. you don't seem to be answering the actual question, but it's not clear since you didn't provide any explanation.

Answer (score 4):

If you can use a regular `UITableViewCell`, simply register it.

In `viewDidLoad`:

`tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "YourCell")`

In `cellForRowAt indexPath`:

`let cell = metricsTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCell", for: indexPath)`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add one prototype cell, can add a UITableViewController to your xib, which has 1 prototype cell initially. This is not the best way (or maybe correct one) but can used in this case.