# Not able to add static UITableViewCell into tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

As I am new in IOS development I am trying to add `CustomeCell` into `tableView` but I can not add it from library.

What I am doing is just drag `TableView` in my `ViewController` and than drag `tableview` cell in it but its added as extra view under `ViewController` 's view not able to add it into tableview.

I am stuck here any idea how can I add cell by drag and drop.

Screen shot :

I know how to add cell by coding but its very lengthy process to add every thing by code.

Any guidence will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.[image][image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sure let me add my view screen shot

Comment: May be you are working with `XIB` not with `sotryboard`.

Comment: Strange i am not able to add any images as i have no enough stack points. Disgusting restrictions

Comment: Yes Nirav i am adding tableview cell in viewcontroller xib.

Comment: You can not add Cell Prototype in your TableView as your are using XIB only, for that you need to transfer to StoryBoard only.

Comment: You can add cell directly in `UITableController` in `UIStoryBoard`, otherwise you can't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot add a PrototypeCell to UITableView inside xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331947/cannot-add-a-prototypecell-to-uitableview-inside-xib-file)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per my experience, you can not add Custom Cell into `TableView` while you are using or editing your **ViewController/View/Cell** into `XIB`.

**For that you have 2 options**

**1st:** Use Storyboard to design your `TableViewCell`.

**2nd:** Create a new custom cell with `XIB` and load it into your `tableView` with `NIB` name like below.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TableViewCell"];
if (cell == nil) {
   // Create a temporary UIViewController to instantiate the custom cell.
   NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
   // Grab a pointer to the first object (presumably the custom cell, as that's all the XIB should contain).
   cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Hope this will help to add cells into XIB.

Comment: Yes by creating custom class i can able to add custom cell in my tableview thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry for late answer, if you're using xib layout check this;

[Cannot add a PrototypeCell to UITableView inside xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331947/cannot-add-a-prototypecell-to-uitableview-inside-xib-file][1])

Answer (score -1):

For this first select your TableView and in the Inspector Window Increase Prototype Cells by 1 as shown in ScreenShot

[image]

Comment: Sorry but there is no prototype cell option in attribute inspector.

Comment: Do you select your tableview first

Comment: Yes i have selected tableview but there is no option like prototype cell.

Comment: I think you are using Static Cell. If you are your Simple tableview in UIViewController then you can't add Static Cells in Table view for Static Cells you have to use UITableViewController. you got my point

Comment: I dont know its static cell or dynamic but i need to use that into my tableview. May be uts dynamic one but here my problem is i am not able to add any cell.

Comment: In the Attribute Inspector there is `Content` Select it and set it as Dynamic Prototypes as seen in above image and then select Prototype Cells

Comment: @GurinderBatth as User is using XIB there is no option like prototype cells as You can not add Prototype cell into XIB.But Yes your answer is right if User is using StoryBoard, because storyboard have prototype cell option and we can add both static and dynamic cell into it.

Comment: hmm Right @CodeChanger for this we have to add another Xib as UITableViewCell and give them UITableViewCell class and add in tableview data source metho