# Interface builder doesn't allow adding Table View Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, interface-builder

For an alert dialog, I added a UITableView, then while I try to Table View Cell the Interface Builders doesn't accept dropping Table View Cell "on" table view, please check screenshot, I should mention the root is UIView, not UIViewController:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using XIB with `UITableView` so You can't directly add cell of table view same like StoryBoard but You need to create separate XIB of `UITableViewCell` use with your table view.

For more information look at below.

[How do you load custom UITableViewCells from Xib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540345/how-do-you-load-custom-uitableviewcells-from-xib-files)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sorry, but prototype cells are available only in storyboard-based projects.

[Cannot add a PrototypeCell to UITableView inside xib file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34331947/cannot-add-a-prototypecell-to-uitableview-inside-xib-file)

You have to create custom UITableViewCell For UITableView